# rewriting standard S4 methods

Tags: r, r-s4

I am rewriting an S4 plot method for my markovchain class. Before the amendments,
I lend plot from statS4 class and would write:

```
setMethod("plot", signature(x="markovchain", y="missing"),
function(x, y, ...){
#code there
  }
)
```

Now I want to add a supplementary parameter to plot, "package" (that will drive the package used for graphing):

```
setMethod("plot", signature(x="markovchain", y="missing"),
function(x, y, package="igraph"...){
#code there
  }
)
```

All this should be put in a package (the markovchain package) that properly passes all checks. How can I do it? How can I properly amend the documentation of the man folder)